# Will using Core Data speed up key-value parsing?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, optimization, core-data

Currently I am downloading and parsing my data from an XML file that is on my server. At one point, I have to check my first XML key value against all of the values from a second XML file and store the matching values into an array of `NSDictionary`s then display them in a tableview. This can take up to about 5 seconds and I want to speed this up.

I am wondering if I download my XML files into a Core Data structure first if this will speed up the this process, so the load time doesn't take as long when checking these values against one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Core Data won't speed up parsing the XML data -- you'll need to parse the XML before adding the data to your Core Data store. It may or may not speed up the next step, where you apparently are looking for matches, but as you haven't really described what's going on there it's difficult to say one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are effectively doing a comparison of the keys in the two XML documents. If you're using XML-based API calls to do that, you may be doing a linear search in XML doc 1 for every key in doc 2. If there are N keys in doc 1 and M keys in doc 2, that's on the order of N * M operations.

Walking through each document just once to get all the keys and add them to something like Core Data (or just an NSDictionary) that's optimized for retrieval by key seems like it could be an improvement, assuming that looking for matches is what's slowing things down. (If most of your time is being spent simply parsing the XML in the first place, you won't gain much by speeding up the matching.)

Comment: For the first document I have created an array of dictionary values, which I cache, The user selects one of those values which I hold onto.. This value is then used to create my second array of NSDictionary values by comparing that saved value against everything thats in the second xml.